# StrPCopy is deprecated. What is the alternative?

Tags: string, delphi

Here's my question:  How do you get rid of the warning that this code gives about StrPCopy being deprecated? Or put another way -- how do I get rid of StrPCopy which I assume will eventually disappear?  I do not want to use the AnsiString unit at all.

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

var
    aAmount: array[0..12] of AnsiChar;
    TempStr: string;
begin
    TempStr := '123456789012';
    StrPCopy(aAmount, TempStr);
    WriteLn(aAmount);
    ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: Reworded the question -- I want to get rid of StrPCopy.

Comment: FWIW, the result will not fit in the array. There is no room for the terminating zero. Note that StrPCopy does not check any lengths, so it will put it somewhere. Rather use StrPLCopy and a length of 12. But AFAICT, StrLCopy (the AnsiChar version) will do the same.

Comment: Fixed code to give room for #0

Comment: StrPCopy simply does `System.AnsiStrings.StrLCopy(Dest, PAnsiChar(Source), Length(Source));`, so you can use that directly.

Comment: I'm asking poorly.  I don't want to use the AnsiString unit at all.

Comment: FWIW, StrPCopy as such is not deprecated, it is just that you are supposed to use `System.AnsiStrings.StrPCopy(...);`instead of a plain `StrPCopy(...);`. See SysUtils.

Comment: @Rudy `System.SysUtils.StrPCopy` is deprecated. That's what Nick is calling one presumes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it turns out you want to do without the `AnsiStrings` unit, simply do:

```
function NicksStrPCopy(const Source: AnsiString; Dest: PAnsiChar): PAnsiChar;
begin
  Move(PAnsiChar(Source)^, Dest^, Length(Source) + 1); // +1 for the 0 char
  Result := Dest;
end;
```

That's a bit low level, but all the other useful routines are defined in the `AnsiStrings` unit too, which you want to avoid.

Comment: This won't work if `Source` is empty. The code in my answer works. You've also reversed the arguments. Still, Nick seems content!!!

Comment: -1 for the issue if Source='' -> Source[1] fails. Pointer(result) is safer, or just use if Source<>'' then move(pointer(result)^,dest^,length(source)+1)

Answer (score 10):

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.StrPCopy) for [`System.SysUtils.StrPCopy`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.StrPCopy) says:

> **Warning**: The ANSI version of StrPCopy is deprecated. Please use the AnsiStrings unit.

So the solution is to call [`System.AnsiStrings.StrPCopy`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.AnsiStrings.StrPCopy) instead.

As an aside, the code in the question has a buffer overrun. Your array is one element too short in length.

---

OK, now you've changed the question. You want to implement `StrPCopy` without using `System.AnsiStrings`. That would go like this:

```
function StrPCopy(Dest: PAnsiChar; const Source: AnsiString): PAnsiChar;
begin
  Result := Dest;
  Move(PAnsiChar(Source)^, Pointer(Dest)^, Length(Source)+1);
end;
```

I'm not quite sure why you don't want to use the `System.AnsiStrings` unit. I don't see any obvious reason to shun it.

Comment: I have the impression Nick thinks it will eventually disappear. I don't think so, at least not for the desktop. Not anytime soon.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis No. I don't see any reason why `System.AnsiStrings` will be removed. Presumably it exists as a repository for all the Ansi functions that aren't offered on mobile.

Comment: Not unless a future version of Windows removes Ansi support, and all prior versions of Windows become no longer supported. But even then, it would probably stay for a few more years. Imagine how much software would break if it were removed.

Comment: Actually the problem might be if the user wants to include SysUtils too (which also has the definition) the compiler starts to complain with an Error E2251 meaning he does not know which version to use... whats the solution here?

Comment: @mrbarat disambiguation `System.AnsiStrings.StrPCopy`